# file size overflow exception occuring mean when doing realm.executetransaction

Tags: java, android, realm

I have encountered this problem here. And it's so frequent on crashlytics :

```
Fatal Exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. File size overflow in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsSharedRealm.cpp line 144
       at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeCommitTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java)
       at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.commitTransaction(OsSharedRealm.java:286)
       at io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction(BaseRealm.java:400)
       at io.realm.Realm.commitTransaction(Realm.java:135)
       at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1395)
```

Of which I cannot make anything. As I have checked for any open realm connections and found none. Also I have checked all of the realm issues regarding this issue and haven't found any similar to this one here.

The line at which its coming is this:

```
 realmObj.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        // some code here
        realmObj.copyToRealmOrUpdate(someObj);
 }
```

Comment: Which version of realm are you using?

Comment: How many objects are you saving in how many transactions?

Comment: @dazza5000 I am using version 4.3.1

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks you are here man. There is only this transaction going on inside a loop inside a worker thread that has closed realm when its done. And the number of objects can be maximum 400 so it can run that much time.

Comment: What happens if you move the loop into the transaction?

Comment: Well I cannot because I need to update each object into the database so the transaction should run for all of them(Please, do correct me as I am a novice).

Comment: What is the real reason behind this exception. What does it really means.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem if you move loop inside transaction block. This way you will be opening the transaction, update all the objects and then committing. Now for every loop you are opening and committing.